# Installing memcached - class exists but not found

Tags: php, memcached, php-extension

This is a very strange problem -

I've installed Memcached 2.1.0 on my 10.7.4 Mac, running 1.7.3 XAMPP with developer tools.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://www.lecloud.net/post/3102678831/install-memcached-php-memcached-extension-under-mac)

1. I've also installed memcache extension too (not memcached).
2. memcached deamon is running and I can telnet data into it.
3. php.ini -> When I use "extension=memcache.so", `phpinfo()` shows that memcache extension is loaded fine.
4. php.ini -> When I use "extension=memcached.so", `phpinfo()` doesn't show memcached extension
5. php.ini -> When I use "extension=memcache.so" AND "extension=memcached.so", `phpinfo()` doesn't show both!

The really strange part is:

1. `class_exists('Memcached')` returns true!
2. `extension_loaded('Memcached')` returns true!
3. `new Memcached()` says class not found.

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Use `Memcache()` if you want to access the daemon; `memcached` is the server daemon that runs as a separate program.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I read that Memcached and Memcache are seperate extensions; Memcached considered the better version. Also, why does class_exists('Memcached') returns true but new Memcached() says class not found? Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Yes, this is rather oddly documented, and I had a few issues with it; [`Memcached`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) and [`Memcache`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) both act as if they are similar, from the documentation, albeit with memcached having the ability to create a server. I've never actually gotten `Memcached()` to work; I just ended up installing the daemon and using the php5-memcache package in my server repo.

Comment: Reading the notes on the PHP installation page: do you have the memcached daemon running? See http://memcached.org

Comment: Yup deamon is running. As I said, I can issue tcp commands to memcached and deamon is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to this issue and it was because of namespaces. Try taking out namespaces if you are using them. See if that works and then work on it from there.